# Calculate time-difference for unique id in other column

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a SQL-table with 4 columns looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv6qf.jpg

Now i want to calculate the time **between** a **start** and **stop** message for a unique order id.

What i need is actually a result table looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXRKG.jpg

Can somebody help me out here? Tried it a long time but got no correct result.

UPDATE: The example tables are simplified. There are also other message types like ready, quit, finished, so min and max date wont work here.

Also my datetime is like: 2018-10-12T15:20:00Z

Comment: Maybe you can just subtract min datetime from max datetime grouped by order id

Comment: did you changed the nls_date_format of your session so that its print time only as hh24:mm??

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply @JaredC. The table i published was just an example. An order id produces also some other status messages, so minimum and maximum date only would work if start and stop would be the first and last message, but they are not.

Comment: Then you will have to do some subqueries to grab the value of start and stop and subtract those. Can you try this and update your question with your attempted code?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, my format is like 2018-04-10T15:12:00Z => ISO 8601

Comment: Only one "start" and one "stop" entry per ID?

Comment: show as your code, and rather than link, upload the image in question

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT order, max(datetime)-min(datetime) as time
from table
where status in('start','stop')
group by order
```

Try this.

Comment: order has many values how to group by it??? it will throw an error!!!!!!

Comment: avoid answering to question with negative point.  when someone puts negative point to question it means question is of low value.  to motivate people to ask good question, low quality question shouldn't be answerd

Comment: It was a simple answer, and he clarified the issue in comments. Can't believe you down voted me for that.